# replace only the alphabets from the last instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a list like:

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '-'];
```

If I have a string like 1234, I can easily replace the last character using slice or substring functions. What should I do to remove only the consecutive alphabets coming at the last instance. E.g. if I have a string like def+1+2-3abcd, the desired result should be def+1+2-3.

Comment: Gee, sounds like a nice homework problem.

Comment: not a homework but an actual faced problem.

Comment: Is my answer what you are looking for? If not, could you please rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic regular expression:

```
var str = "def+1+2-3abcd";
var replaced = str.replace(/[a-z]+$/,"");  //match a-z - one or more - at the end of the string
console.log(replaced);
```